# Google Apps Script Create QR Code from Cell Value from Google and send the QR Code to email

Tags: google-apps-script, qr-code

I want to convert a value of a cell from column I to a QR code and send it to an email preferably as PNG or JPEG. I have already done on sending the email text part but when I tried other ways, it sends the email text but for the attached qr code, it only displays gibberish symbols on the email. I only know how to convert a cell value to a QR code in sheets but not in app script.

[Gibberish symbols on previous attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfJ5I.png)
[Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOPsd.png)

Here is my code for the app script.

```
function sendEmail()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var templateText = sheet.getRange(1,7).getValue();
  var tickNum = 1;
  var emailAddressQR = "printerqr@gmail.com";

// i is row number then  column number
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)
  { 
    var tickNum2 = i - tickNum;
    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();

    var name = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
    var subjectLine = ("QR Code #" + tickNum2 + " " +name);
    /////PROBLEM QR CODE ATTACHED to email
    var qrImage = sheet.getRange(i,9).getValue();
    var url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&data="+ encodeURIComponent(qrImage);
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    var blobImage = ImageItem.getImage(blob);
    var emailBody = templateText.replace("{num}",tickNum2) + blobImage;
    /////
    var emailSent = sheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
    var confirmEmail = sheet.getRange(i,6); //sent to user or user and printer
    var qrCodeTickNum = sheet.getRange(i,7); //qr code #
    var confirmEmailValue = confirmEmail.getValue();

    if (confirmEmailValue == "")
    { 
      if (emailSent == "No")
      {
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subjectLine, emailBody);
        confirmEmail.setValue("Sent to user");
        qrCodeTickNum.setValue(tickNum2);
        continue
      }

      if (emailSent == "Yes")
      {
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddressQR, subjectLine, emailBody);
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subjectLine, emailBody);
        confirmEmail.setValue("Sent to printer and user");
        qrCodeTickNum.setValue(tickNum2);
        continue
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

For the code attached, it displays an error on the script for the line with getImage()

Comment: What is `ImageItem.getImage(blob)`?

Comment: I just tried to get value of blob as an image and i just read that somewhere in apps script so i only assumed it is. not really familiar in using appscripts